# Not able to refresh WPF Combobox inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I am new in WPF and I need to bind combobox inside datagrid based on button click outside datagrid. Means every time when I click on button combobox inside datagrid should be refresh.

[image]

[image]

I am able to bind source column combobox but it is not getting refreshed when I click on Apply button by changing source file as shown in above image.

XAML Code that I did for this is

```
<Grid Name="grdMappedTables" Margin="0,109,466,28" Background="LightGray">
<Grid.Resources>
                      <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SourceDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:SourceTable}" MethodName="FillSourceTableCol" ></ObjectDataProvider>

  </Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid Name="dgMappedTables" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" CanUserAddRows="False"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow" Style="{DynamicResource AzureDataGrid}" GridLinesVisibility="All" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn  Width="25" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False"  >
               </DataGridTextColumn>

               <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Source" Width="200" CanUserResize="False" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=column_id}" SelectedValuePath="column_id" DisplayMemberPath="column_name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SourceDataProvider}}">
                                 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                   <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"></Setter>
                             </Style>
                                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Target" Width="200" CanUserResize="False" >

                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>                                 
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
```

Code behind class is used for this is

```
public class SourceTable
{
    public DataView FillSourceTableCol()
    {
        DataTable dtSourceTable = new DataTable();
        dtSourceTable = CommonDBClass.GetTable("select column_id, column_name from systabcol", strConnectionString);
        return dtSourceTable.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

How should I refresh combobox when click on Apply button?

Comment: What about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your class ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aybe. I did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged class. I am not much aware of this class. Can you please tell me what is the benefit by implementing this class in this scenario??

Comment: Whenever you will change the property from your code, the subscriber to it (your ComboBox) will fetch the value automatically, i.e. no need to do funky stuff about refreshing it. You can either implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use dependency properties. As an advice you should at MVVM concept and also use a better data grid such as Xceed (free).

Comment: How can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and where should I implement in my code? It is good if you give me an example.